# What is a good way to capture a video on linux?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, screencast

I need to capture a part of my screen which shows the video. The video looks something like the top-left corner of this screenshot:

[image: The video looks something like top left corner of this screenshot]

What is a good tool for doing this on Ubuntu 14.04? I have tried RecordMyDesktop but it corrupts the video if the video is too fast and if the video is full screen. Is there any other good tool I can use which precisely captures the screen-area I want to, in high definition?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Kazam Screencaster](https://launchpad.net/kazam), it's the best for myself. Here is a [tutorial for ubuntu 14.04](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AkIIduiV6ws).